# Creating a cascading list between sites

Tags: list, 2007, cascading

I am attempting to create a link/cascading column between lists located in separate sites. Is this possible in out of the box SP07? I am only finding this functionality if using lookup columns in the same site.

Answer (score 1):

You can add lookup columns to Site Collection parent site and have it reflect as lookup within child sites by creating the site column as lookup. But cross site collection, it is not possible OOTB. There are 3rd party solutions available if you search for "Sharepoint 2007 Cross Site lookup".